# Android apps: making shell command-line tools that executes stuff in the app

Tags: android, command-line

I know how to start activities through a shell, run shell commands through Java, etc. But what about creating a command-line tool in Java? I want the user to be able to use the GUI as well as a CLI (i.e. adb shell or a Terminal emulator).

Is it possible to write the code in Java? Or do I need to delve into the NDK? Being able to write it in Java would be a lot easier due to all the available libraries etc.

Comment: It is possible to write an executable or script which launches a java program in a Davlik VM (see for example the source of the 'am' command), however it will be very tricky to make use of  Android platform (vs generic Java) capabilities.  To do so, you may be stuck having to use an Intent to launch an android Activity or Service and asking it to interact with the the Android platform.